# how to replace current date mmddyyyy in a file in a batch program

Tags: windows, batch-file

hope i can find an answer for what i'am trying.

i've a file named `JOFAACKR.WSDFHER1.08092012.GILLJOCAR.J8RJXV2Y_SumRpt.JOBAACKR` on a remote  server, i need to get this file onto my server. i wrote a download program that does get me the file perfectly when i mention exact filename. Now i'am trying to pass a  date value through a variable.
  `set mmddyyyy=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%`
   so, can i write something like `*.%mmddyyyy%.*.JOBAACKR` to get the files named with current date?

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\> set mydate=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%
C:\> echo %mydate%
03082013
```